# Decoder issue when executing lua script on redis through RedissonScript

Tags: redis, lua, redisson

I have a lua script -

```
if redis.call('EXISTS', KEYS[1]) == 1 then
    return 'A'
else
    return 'B'
end
```

When i try to execute this through RedissonScript

```
client.getScript().eval(RScript.Mode.READ_WRITE, luaScript, RScript.ReturnType.MULTI, Collections.singletonList("ABC"))
```

I get a "CommandDecoder - Unable to decode data. unsupported protocol version 66" error? I do not get an error when i try to return a boolean or integer value instead of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `client.getScript(StringCodec.INSTANCE).eval()` method